# Chained and Unchained Replication In Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

In MongoDB there are two types of replication: Chained replication and Un-Chained replication. Which one is the default replication method?

Comment: MongoDB enables `chained` replication by default.

Answer (score 0):

It supports Chained by default as mentioned in MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/faq/replica-sets/)